# Django's caching middleware not working in Gunicorn with Debug=False

Tags: django, caching, gunicorn

I have a Django project deployed with Gunicorn and nginx. I also have a memcached running and the Django cache middleware () set up to cache the site.

Everything works fine when running with DEBUG=True, but when I switch to DEBUG=False I get the following error in Gunicorn log when trying to access the site:

```
2013-02-20 16:09:50 [25196] [ERROR] Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/toursprung/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 102, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/home/toursprung/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/toursprung/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 247, in __call__
    status_text = STATUS_CODE_TEXT[response.status_code]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

The strange thing is, that I get another error in the error email Django is sending me. Here I get the following: (An error in the GZIP Middleware. wtf?)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/toursprung/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 188, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "/home/toursprung/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/middleware/gzip.py", line 16, in process_response
    if len(response.content) < 200:
  File "/home/toursprung/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 699, in _get_content
    return ''.join([str(e) for e in self._container])

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\x8b' in position 26: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Anyone a clue why this is happening?

Thanks in advance,
Anton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the ordering of my middlewares!

This is the ordering I had, which is **wrong**:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'myproject.middleware.StripCookieMiddleware', # fix caching problem with analytics cookies
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    ...
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware'
)
```

I moved the `GZipMiddleware` right below the `UpdateCacheMiddleware` (ok, there is my little middleware that strips google analytics cookies in between) and now everything is working as expected.

So this is the **right** order of middlewares:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'myproject.middleware.StripCookieMiddleware', # fix caching problem with analytics cookies
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    ...
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware'
)
```

Maybe this will help somebody in the future...