# Django won't serve pages - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tags'

Tags: django

I am setting up my site on a production server and have hit a brick wall.
The error below appears running django with gunicorn or just via "manage.py runserver"
Gunicorn/runserver starts fine but when a page is requested this error is reported.
Any advice on where to look or possible causes would be gratefully appreciated.

```
File "/home/geoff/virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 125, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/home/geoff/virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/geoff/virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/geoff/virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/geoff/virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 221, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/home/geoff/virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 66, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "/home/geoff/virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 285, in get_traceback_html
    t = Template(TECHNICAL_500_TEMPLATE, name='Technical 500 template')
  File "/home/geoff/virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 125, in __init__
    self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
  File "/home/geoff/virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 152, in compile_string
    parser = parser_class(lexer.tokenize())
  File "/home/geoff/virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 35, in __init__
    super(DebugParser, self).__init__(lexer)
  File "/home/geoff/virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 232, in __init__
    self.add_library(lib)
  File "/home/geoff/virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 339, in add_library
    self.tags.update(lib.tags)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tags'
```

Comment: [Would this help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983473/djangos-caching-middleware-not-working-in-gunicorn-with-debug-false)

Comment: not really.  It does not work with DEBUG True or False.  The middleware was working fine on the dev server as well

Comment: so if I put 'return HttpResponse("hello world")' in my view then it works ok.  However using render_to_response with a template produces the error above

Answer (score 1):

If you are updating to django 1.5, removing:

```
django.contrib.admin.templatetags.adminmedia
```

From:

TEMPLATE_TAG_MODULES in settings.py

This will dismiss the error.